# Increment count for value in foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am trying to count the instances of rfid from one array to insert into another array so I can use this data to create charts.

At the moment my code is as follows

```
if ($message == "Broken" && $message_type == "BreakBeam" && $previous==$cat_id) {
            
            $total = 1;
            
            $splitTimeStamp = explode(" ",$eventtime);
            $date = $splitTimeStamp[0];
            $time = $splitTimeStamp[1];
        
            $events[$c]['date'] = $date;
            $events[$c]['device'] = $device;
            $events[$c]['time']= $time;
            $events[$c]['rfid']= $previous;
            $events[$c]['count']=$total;
            $c++;
        }   
        }  


        $a = array();
        $i=0;

        foreach($events as $event){
          if(isset($a[$event['rfid']])){
            $a['rfid_id'][$event['rfid']]++;
          }else{
            $a['rfid_id'][$event['rfid']]=1;
          }
          if(isset($a[$event['date']])){
            $a['dateinsert'][$event['date']]++;
          }else{
            $a['dateinsert'][$event['date']] =1;        
           }
        }



    $rfid = array();
    // those are the ones we're going to put in!

    foreach($a as $key => $count) {
      foreach($count as $eventdetails['rfid_id'] => $event){
      // so $key is the [rfid] key of the entry and $count is the count (all 1's?) in it
    if (isset($rfid[$key])) {
      $rfid[$key]+=$event;
    }
    else {
      $rfid[$key]=$event;
    }
    }
  }
```

Which outputs as follows :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-17
            [device] => 2
            [time] => 15:51:37
            [rfid] => 23641
            [count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-17
            [device] => 2
            [time] => 15:52:20
            [rfid] => 5609
            [count] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-17
            [device] => 2
            [time] => 15:53:23
            [rfid] => 5609
            [count] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2020-09-17
            [device] => 2
            [time] => 16:02:44
            [rfid] => 5609
            [count] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [rfid_id] => Array
        (
            [23641] => 1
            [5609] => 1
        )

    [dateinsert] => Array
        (
            [2020-09-17] => 1
        )

)
Array
(
    [rfid_id] => 2
    [dateinsert] => 1
)
```

Ideally, I would like to achieve the following :

```
Array
(
    [rfid_id] => Array
        (
            [23641] => 1
            [5609] => 3
        )

    [dateinsert] => Array
        (
            [2020-09-17] => 1
        )

)
```

or something to that effect, where I can look at the date, rfid codes and the time each was read on that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply missing the path in the assignment loop.

Same goes for `rfid` and `date` so I just explain on `rfid`.
You check the `isset` on one path but is not exist set on another - this cause the path to never exist - that why you keep getting 1's.

Look at:

```
foreach($events as $event){
  if(isset($a[$event['rfid']])){
    $a['rfid_id'][$event['rfid']]++;
  } else {
    $a['rfid_id'][$event['rfid']]=1;
  }
}
```

Notice `$a[$event['rfid']]` is NOT the same as `$a['rfid_id'][$event['rfid']]`.

You should change the if statement to be: `if (isset($a['rfid_id'][$event['rfid']))`